# Git. How can I track file (folder) only in one branch

Tags: git, branch

My objective is to get file tracked, but not to be noised by changes in it. Actually it is IDE specific project settings folder. I'd like to save it. But when I tracked it, commited to separate branch and checouted master it was tracked in master too.

Now changes in project settings are present in working directory. It is messing me and I have to put changes to separate change set in my IDE. Though I don't like it. Is it possible to hide this changes from woking directory but still have those changes tracked in separate branch?

Any suggestions will be appreciated! (I believe there is more elegant solution)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good use case for git. Git is meant for tracking content, not storing content and then ignoring it.

Therefore any mechanism for achieving this isn't optimal.

- `.gitignore` only ignores untracked content, so it doesn't work for tracked content.
- `git update-index --assume-unchanged` is basically a promise to git that the file won't change. Changing it then breaks this promise, with all problems related to it. Switching branches or merges can fail because git suddenly sees that the file *has* changed.

You have to asked why you need the files to be tracked. If you need some sort of template that can be distributed, then add it as a template (under a different name), and track that, but ignore the actual files that can change.

*Edit for clarity:*

A template in this case is nothing really special. It's just the data you want to track, but under a different name. Anyone who needs the data, can then make a copy of the template and use that.

Comment: The meaning of "template" isn't clear for me. Could you explain it?

Comment: I need the files to be saved in any way. I tried Git because it is already used for version control. If this usecase is inapropriate for Git, what tool should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use separate repository for your own IDE files.

1. You can place your IDE repository in subdirectory of your main project. `git status` will always show your IDE folder as untracked but you can avoid it with `.gitignore`. Don't try to add and commit subrepository.
2. Better approach not to mix IDE files/directories and main project. Place IDE files in another directory and symlink them into working directory with proper name. This solution can be applied only in Linux/Mac OS.